# Updating Data in Firebase using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am updating an object in firebase using React js. 
I'm using this [boilerplate as reference](https://github.com/btomashvili/react-redux-firebase-boilerplate/blob/476c34c8f283f38d7ffefe729b0ce0e0c1a0ff9b/src/app/actions/firebase_actions.js).

```
  updateBookList: (id, data) => {
    return firebaseDb.ref('NewBooks').child(id).update(data).then(() => {
      return {};
    }).catch(error => {
      return {
        errorCode: error.code,
        errorMessage: error.message
      }
    });
  },
```

The following updates the Books fine.

What I want to do is return the result instead of returning a blank {}. How can I return the result of what I updated?

This is how I fetch books:

```
  fetchBooks: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const bookSub = firebaseDb.ref('NewBooks').on("value", books => {
        resolve(books.val());
      }, error => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return the value, you need to retrieve it. You can do that using [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) and the `value` event, which returns a promise that resolves to a Firebase [snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot):

```js
updateBookList: (id, data) => {
  let ref = firebaseDb.ref('NewBooks');
  return ref
    .child(id)
    .update(data)
    .then(() => ref.once('value'))
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
    .catch(error => ({
      errorCode: error.code,
      errorMessage: error.message
    }));
}
```

Also, you could simplify your `fetchBooks` by using `once` there, too:

```js
fetchBooks: () => {
  return firebaseDb.ref('NewBooks')
    .once("value")
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.val());
}
```

`once` returns a promise, so you don't have to create your own and you won't have a dangling event listener. The call to `on` in your implementation of `fetchBooks` will see a listener added with each call and multiple calls to `resolve` will be attempted if the database changes.